# Where can I find large datasets of protein-interaction networks?

Tags: bioinformatics, database, protein-interaction, proteomics

Where do I find large datasets of protein interaction networks for cancer or alzheimer diseases?  So far, I found [String](https://string-db.org/) but it is does not have enough proteins for my purposes. Are there such databases with more entries?
I'm still open to any proposition of the disease to choose from . 
the most important part is the volume of data .
And how can I get the annotation of each protein  of the extracted network from Uniprot ?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I edited your question to make it more clear. Please feel free to further edit. Thanks!

Comment: The String database is one of the best available, how many proteins do you need? (consider that the human genome is predicted to have around 25k protein-coding genes)

Comment: @alec_djinn I need for about 5k or 6k proteins for alzheimer or cancer  but i don't know how to retreive that quantity at once

Comment: @AM I can't find the exact number of entries for the human proteins, maybe you should contact them, 5k sounds reasonable, I would expect them to have it. If not, maybe you can integrate with other mammalian proteins. As far I know, STRING is the most complete you can find now.

Comment: @alec_djinn Okay. Thank you, I will contact them

Comment: @AM What makes you think you can find 5k proteins for Alzheimer? Do you hypothesise that 1/5 of the human genome is involved in Alzheimer?
Nevertheless, you could take the genes in the KEGG pathway for Alzheimer disease, or take the genes known to be genetically causative for or associated with AD and include all their interactors. I think the network will get quite big as such.

Comment: @alec_djinn ehm, the STRING database is one of the *largest* available but absolutely not one of the best. Probably the worst, actually, in that it has a lot of crappy data in there. Unless you are knowledgeable enough to parse out the bad stuff, do not recommend it.

Comment: @AM please [edit] your question and clarify your needs. Do you want to limit the results to binary interactions only? Are you also interested in non-direct interactions like forming part of the same complex? Do you want only experimentally verified interactions or also those inferred by electronic annotations? Do you have a list of proteins of interest? Please add more details.

Comment: @WouterDeCoster would you suggest me an application where i can get such huge dataset ?  I'm not really limited to Azheimer it was just a proposition . I'm open to any disease which will get me this proportion of data

Comment: @terdon if it is not then what database would you recommend ? I do not have a protein of interest, I only want a huge dataset of protein protein interaction  for a disease , that's all I'm open to any suggestions .

Comment: @AM yes, but what do you mean by "protein-protein interactions for a disease"? How would you define the list of proteins you care about? You normally start with a small list of "bait" proteins and then collect their interactors, moving as many steps down the network as you need.

Comment: @terdon  I do not care about the list pf proteins I need , more than the idea of a specific network for a disease , having 4k to 5k of proteins that's all

Comment: I don't know how you could even define that. Whether you include a protein in the list of proteins involved in a disease depends very much on how you define disease association. Is it only proteins with a function affecting this disease? Is it also the proteins that interact with them? How many steps removed? How about proteins controlling the expression of related genes? Or proteins that interact with those? Or should it only be protein interactions whose disruptions affect the disease? And should that include ubiquitous proteins that are involved in almost everything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bunch of decent protein-protein interaction databases: Biocarta, BioGrid, DIP, InnateDB, IntAct, MINT, PPID.
Some of them aren't available now, but you can download datasets from the Expression2Kinases [download](http://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/X2K/#downloads) page because they are integrated into [X2K pipeline](http://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/X2K/) as part of Genes2Networks analysis. If you need more proteins, you can submit your list of proteins to X2K and use G2N analysis to connect enriched transcription factors through known protein-protein interactions.

Also, the new dataset called [hu.MAP](http://proteincomplexes.org/) was published recently. It is a dataset of human protein-protein interactions determined by over 9,000 mass spectrometry experiments performed by the Marcotte Lab from UT Austin. A paper that describes the hu.MAP project is available on [Biorxiv](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2016/12/07/092361).

[BioPlex](http://bioplex.hms.harvard.edu/) (**b**iophysical **i**nteractions of **O**RFeome-based com**plex**es) is another database with experimental verification. Authors describe it as a network that is

> the result of creating thousands of cell lines with each expressing a
>   tagged version of a protein from the ORFeome collection.
>   Immunopurification of the tagged protein and detection of associated
>   proteins by mass spectrometry are the building blocks of the network.
>   The overarching project goal is to determine protein interactions for
>   every member of the collection.

Comment: I have checked IntAct, and it kind of offers what I've been looking for , I'm wondering If there is a way to  extract all the associated proteins' annotations from uniprot  . because I need to get all the annotations of every protein contained in the dataset